# Creating Pandas Dataframe with Generators instead of Lists for performance efficiency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, generator, list-comprehension

This question is related to a former question posted here:

[list comprehensions with break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61468089/list-comprehensions-with-break/61469873#61469873)

I want to create a Pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
   0  1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0  4  5  6   9  10  16  21  23  25  27
1  5  7  7  11  11  17  24  24  26  56
```

And this is the code that I have written so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import timeit
from bisect import bisect_left

list1 = [4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 16, 21, 23, 25, 27]
list2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 20, 24, 26, 56]

# List comprehension with []
list3 = [list2[bisect_left(list2,i+1)] for i in list1]
print(list3)

# List comprehension with ()
list3_with_gen = (list2[bisect_left(list2,i+1)] for i in list1)
print(list3_with_gen)

# Timing the []
print(timeit.timeit('''

import timeit
from bisect import bisect_left

list1 = [4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 16, 21, 23, 25, 27]
list2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 20, 24, 26, 56]

list3 = [list2[bisect_left(list2,i+1)] for i in list1]

'''))

# Timing the ()
print(timeit.timeit('''

import timeit
from bisect import bisect_left

list1 = [4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 16, 21, 23, 25, 27]
list2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 20, 24, 26, 56]

list3 = (list2[bisect_left(list2,i+1)] for i in list1)

'''))

df = pd.DataFrame([list1, list3])
print(df)



# # original for loops
# list3 = []
# for i in list1:
#     for j in list2:
#         if j>i:
#             # print(i,j)
#             list3.append(j)
#             break
# # print(list1)
# # print(list3)
```

The output of the code is:

```
[5, 7, 7, 11, 11, 17, 24, 24, 26, 56]
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000016618C46548>
3.8416419
1.3952507
   0  1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0  4  5  6   9  10  16  21  23  25  27
1  5  7  7  11  11  17  24  24  26  56
```

What does the code do?

- It compares the timing of creating list3 with 'List comprehension with []' and list3_with_gen with 'List comprehension with ()'.
- The timing of 'List comprehension with ()' is about 3x faster.

I have some issues fully understanding generators, and it's not because of lack of trying. My objective is to create the dataframe as quickly and efficiently as possible, because this is a small sample and the lists have large dimensions.

Is there a way that I can create that dataframe using the list3_with_gen generator object, since it is about 3x times faster to create?

Comment: you can try `pd.DataFrame([list1, list(list3_with_gen)])`, it is a bit faster (about 20%) but not 3 times faster to create the dataframe

Comment: in your application, are either of these lists held constant between calls, or are you given two new sorted lists each time the function is called?

Comment: with list lengths M and N the original solution with comprehensions is `O(N*M)`, the bisect version is `O(N*log(M))`.  A merge sort approach could be `O(max(N,M))`

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not use a generator, but its performance is linear in the lengths of input lists 1 and 2.  For larger lists it should beat the naive comprehension and comprehension-with-bisect:

```
def merge(lst1, lst2):
    ret = []
    j = 0
    for elem in lst1:
        while(lst2[j] <= elem):
            j += 1
        ret.append(lst2[j])
    return ret

list1 = [4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 16, 21, 23, 25, 27]
list2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 20, 24, 26, 56]

print(merge(list1, list2))
```

prints

```
[5, 7, 7, 11, 11, 17, 24, 24, 26, 56]
```

To get the requested DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

def merge(lst1, lst2):
    ret = []
    j = 0
    for elem in lst1:
        while(lst2[j] <= elem):
            j += 1
        ret.append([elem, lst2[j]])
    return ret

list1 = [4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 16, 21, 23, 25, 27]
list2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 20, 24, 26, 56]

merged = merge(list1, list2)
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*merged))
print(df)
```

prints

```
   0  1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0  4  5  6   9  10  16  21  23  25  27
1  5  7  7  11  11  17  24  24  26  56
```

Comment: If you really want a generator replace `ret.append([elem, lst2[j]])` with `yield [elem, lst2[j]]` in the `merge()` function.